# can not play avi file on ubuntu 18.04 lts

Tags: sound, video, vlc, avi

Can not play  avi file from Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (64 bit OS)

`vlc` just showing black screen

Comment: add the contents of `file {your_avi_file}` to the question please.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure why maybe your multimedia dont have the dependency to run that file. try-

sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras   (this contains most of the multimedia codecs)

AND

sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-addons

OR ELSE if while installing vlc maybe it didnt install the dependency  so also run 
sudo apt-get install -f